# ui-router: multiple paramaters when html5mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this URL working with ui-router: http://example.com/param1, so home (/) with one pending parameter, using:

`...state("home",{
        url: "/:id",
        template...`

However when I add a second parameter `url: "/:id1/:id2"`, the first param is interpreted as a directory and all files are fetched like `http://example.com/param1/assets/angularjs.min.js`

What do I have to do to have multiple parameters?

Comment: It seems like a problem with your server side routing, as opposed to a problem with Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint, it was a wrong htaccess code. This one is working:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```